# need jdk 1.6 to compile java program

Tags: java

i need to install jdk 1.6. and a suitable eclipse.can anyone suggest a good link for free download. My oS version is window 7 home premium.
By mistakenly i uninstalled my default jre
Or any other suggestions are also welcome.

what version of JRE, JDK and Eclipse i should exactly use to run a java programs.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered with a google search.

Comment: yes, i tried. actually i was searching for 1.6, but in all the sites i found jad1.8 the latest version . where as for 1.8 version i saw the review is its not fully compatible with all. so got confused and asked here for better suggestion.

Comment: It can be also this way, the OP is unable to figure out from the ocean of google search results. Offcourse, in such a case, it also means you really dont need the answer, the problem is the problem. But I posted a reply with some specific links in case he is able to figure it out. Please correct me if i did wrong w.r.to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to read on Java, JDK, JRE, JVM to know what they are and why you need them.
http://codinko.com/2014/01/04/platformvmjvmjrejdk-etc/

Eclipse:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2

JDK, JRE downloads:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The one stop shop - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get [Oracle's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) Java JDK for free, and [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) too. Both are free of course.